# Netlogo: how to make a list of single characters from a text string?

Tags: string, list, netlogo

Is there a simple way to build such a list without iterating over the string?

Actually I want to build a list of turtles, where each turtle owns a variable holding one character from the string.

Thanks,
Palle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your who of your turtles start at 0, you can do the following where you access the who-th element of the string: otherwise, you'd need to do an offset.

```
let somestring "thecat"

ask turtles where [who < (length somestring)] [set my-char (item who somestring)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Matt has solved your actual problem, but to also answer your original question ("how to make a list of single characters from a text string?"):

```
to-report explode [s]
  report map [n -> item n s] n-values (length s) [n -> n]
end
```

sample usage:

```
observer> show explode "foobar"
observer: ["f" "o" "o" "b" "a" "r"]
```

I have a hunch there's some simpler way, but I can't think of one right now.

You could also use https://github.com/NetLogo/String-Extension which has `explode`.